# Why do we need "MultiOutputClassifier" if we can get same results without it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am learning about multi-label multi-classification examples

It is when you have a case like this

```
Year   Actor     Budget      |   Genre
------------------------------------------------
2004   Tom C.    40,000,000  |   Action, Darama
2016   Mel G.    54,000,000  |   Comedy, Action, Family
2021   Eva K.    3,000,000   |   Comedy, Romance
```

I saw an example using MultiOutputClassifier but I do not see a value of using this classifier as models still work without it, without any problem.

Here is the example, you will see that at **line (1)** which is without **MultiOutputClassifier**, the results are similar to **line (2)** with **MultiOutputClassifier**

so in that case why would anyone use **MultiOutputClassifier**?

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import numpy as np
import datetime



def time_to_sec(dt):
   ms = (dt.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + dt.seconds) * 1000 + dt.microseconds / 1000.0
   ms = ms / 1000.0
   return ms


X, y1 = make_classification(n_samples=100000, n_features=100, n_informative=30, n_classes=3, random_state=1)
y2 = shuffle(y1, random_state=1)
y3 = shuffle(y1, random_state=2)
Y = np.vstack((y1, y2, y3)).T
n_samples, n_features = X.shape # 10,100
n_outputs = Y.shape[1] # 3
n_classes = 3


forest = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)
Tx = datetime.datetime.now()
forest.fit(X, Y).predict(X)  # <------------------------------- (1)
Ty = datetime.datetime.now()
Sec1 = time_to_sec(Tx-Ty)

multi_target_forest = MultiOutputClassifier(forest, n_jobs=-1)
Tx = datetime.datetime.now()
multi_target_forest.fit(X, Y).predict(X)  # <------------------ (2)
Ty = datetime.datetime.now()
Sec2 = time_to_sec(Tx-Ty)

print("Time spend for line (1) = " + str(Sec1))
print("Time spend for line (2) = " + str(Sec2))
```

Comment: cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/108114/55122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every model supports multi-output supervised learning. [`MultiOutputClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html) is a convenient way to train independent single-output models so that you don't have to manually for-loop through every output and clone your base model. You also benefit from parallelization (see `n_jobs` parameter).

---

Note that [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) takes into account possible relationship between outputs by calculating the average reduction across all outputs. So it is not equivalent to `MultiOutputClassifier` as it creates only one, overall model.